# Regex string between square brackets only if '.' is within string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to detect the text between two square brackets in Python however I only want the result where there is a "." within it.

I currently have [(.*?] as my regex, using the following example:

**String To Search:**
CASE[Data Source].[Week] = 'THIS WEEK'

**Result:**
Data Source, Week

However I need the whole string as [Data Source].[Week], (square brackets included, only if there is a '.' in the middle of the string). There could also be multiple instances where it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write a pattern matching `[...]` and then repeat 1 or more times a `.` and again `[...]`

```
\[[^][]*](?:\.\[[^][]*])+
```

**Explanation**

- `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[...]` using a negated character class
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\.\[[^][]*]` Match a dot and again `[...]`
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/utNicm/1).

To get multiple matches, you can use re.findall

```
import re

pattern = r"\[[^][]*](?:\.\[[^][]*])+"

s = ("CASE[Data Source].[Week] = 'THIS WEEK'\n"
            "CASE[Data Source].[Week] = 'THIS WEEK'")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['[Data Source].[Week]', '[Data Source].[Week]']
```

---

If you also want the values of between square brackets when there is not dot, you can use an alternation with lookaround assertions:

```
\[[^][]*](?:\.\[[^][]*])+|(?<=\[)[^][]*(?=])
```

**Explanation**

- `\[[^][]*](?:\.\[[^][]*])+` The same as the previous pattern
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\[)[^][]*(?=])` Match `[...]` asserting `[` to the left and `]` to the right

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eeaj27/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative approach could be:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("(\[[^\]]*\]\.\[[^\]]*\])")

print(pattern.findall(sss))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['[Data Source].[Week]']
```